# Twitter Web Intent Callbacks not working in IE

Tags: javascript, twitter

I've been trying to get the callback to work after a user completes a tweet.  Everything works great in all browsers except for Internet Explorer (11, 10, 9, or 8).  IE shows nothing in the console and the callback just doesn't fire.

Anyone have a solution?  Here is a simple example to illustrate the problem ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n8ueF/)) :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?&text=Test%20Message">Testing</a>

 <script>
  twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
    twttr.events.bind('tweet', function(event) {alert('twitter click');});
   });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you see this topic: https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/3102

Comment: Yeah, no solutions though. Someone mentioned DOCTYPE, but I haven't found a value that works.

Comment: I tested it here http://jsfiddle.net/n8ueF/ IE doesn't fire event for me too :(

Comment: This is bug in IE i guess. If you click on tweet link, the popup is open. Then reclick on this link without closing previous popup, a new popup open. If in new popup you tweet the message, then the tweet event is fired. The first popup doesn't seem to trigger event in all case

Comment: Sorry forgot to add a jsfiddle to illustrate it. See if you click on tweet1 then without closing popup click on tweet2 and send inside popup2 the message, the tweet event is fired: http://jsfiddle.net/DrEYL/ I have no idea for any workaround at the moment

Comment: Been working on this the last few days and no luck with IE here either (versions 8-11).  Tried the flash upgrade and Doctypes changes but neither have worked

Comment: @Georgio_1999 ever figure this out? I am experiencing the same issue.

Comment: @Brad no but let me know if you have a break through!

Comment: @Brad any change you figured out this problem? Many months later and A.Wolff's example still doesn't work in IE11.

Comment: @Georgio_1999 any change you figured out this problem? Many months later and A.Wolff's example still doesn't work in IE11.

Comment: @Kevin Nope - I'm afraid not

Comment: @KevinZych unfortunately not.

Comment: Thanks guys. I just noticed a typo in my comments: "any chance*" if you didn't figure that one out :)

Answer (score 0):

This is due to broken postMessage functionality when sending data between windows in IE. IE supports postMessage to iframes since IE8 but not between main window and pop-up window, unlike other prominent browsers which support both.

Reference: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2009/09/16/bugs-in-ie8-support-for-html5-postmessage-sessionstorage-and-localstorage.aspx